# MFC CDateTimeCtrl SetTime Issue

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a CDateTimeCtrl in my code for time which is initialized by current time and is enabled/disabled and time setting is done by click of a tree control.

Now, when I click an item of tree control, first the dateTime control is enabled and a time is set according to data present in my tree control (Say 14:25:17).

Then, when I click on another item of tree control, time is set in the time control (Say 14:26:30).

Now, when I click again on previous tree item, although my SetTime function is called with correct time value (which is 14:25:17) but time which is set and displayed in the control is not updated (it still is 14:26:30).

The GetTime also returns 14:26:30 value.

The code I am using to set the time is:

```
UINT64_T newSTime = info.m_uiStartTime / 1000;    // Time I receive from tree control (in msecs)
CTime start_time(newSTime);
m_StartTime.SetTime(&start_time);
```

I have tried SetRedraw, Invalidate, UpdateData but nothing is working.

Hope you guys can suggest something.

Comment: If GetTime returns 14:26:30, then SetRedraw, Invalidate and UpdateData are senseless. What is the value of start_time? What is the return value if SetTime? It's always a good idea to put VERIFY() around functions calls to detect problems in debug. I guess that you built an invalid time and SetTime fails.